# Apply function for ever identifier in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
|user_id|prch_type|purchase_dt|
-------------------------------
|   1   |     F    |2020-01-01|
|   1   |     F    |2020-01-02|
|   1   |     F    |2020-01-03|
|   1   |     F    |2020-01-03|
|   2   |     F    |2020-02-01|
|   2   |     P    |2020-02-03|
```

I would like that for every user_id for 'prch_type'='F' do the following:

- Calculate the total date between all his purchases (max(purchase_dt) - min(purchase_dt))
- Count all the purchases between the range.
- Create a new column 'all_purchases'/'total_time' with the new columns mentioned above

So it looks like

```
|user_id|purch_freq|
--------------------
|   1   |    2     | #4 purch 2 days
|   2   |    1     | # 1 purch 1 day
```

Can this be done with one function? Or better to use gradually transformations? I'd prefer first, thanks!

Comment: try groupby with data and id

Comment: Please post your exact expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal it is already at  the end of the message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First filter only `F` rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and aggregate counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with difference `max` and `min` by [`numpy.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html), last divide column with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and remove column converted to days. Also if one day only get `0`, so replaced to `1` for correct output.

```
df = df[df['prch_type'].eq('F')]
         .groupby('user_id').agg(purch_freq = ('purchase_dt','size'),
                                 new = ('purchase_dt', np.ptp))

df['purch_freq'] /= df.pop('new').dt.days.replace(0,1)
print (df)
         purch_freq
user_id            
1               2.0
2               1.0
```

If need `0` for not matched rows (added `user_id=3`) in sample data:

```
print (df)
   user_id prch_type purchase_dt
0        1         F  2020-01-01
1        1         F  2020-01-02
2        1         F  2020-01-03
3        1         F  2020-01-03
4        2         F  2020-02-01
5        2         P  2020-02-03
6        3         P  2020-02-01
7        3         P  2020-02-03

df = (df.assign(purchase_dt = df['purchase_dt'].where(df['prch_type'].eq('F')))
        .groupby('user_id').agg(purch_freq = ('purchase_dt','count'),
                                new = ('purchase_dt', np.ptp)))

df['purch_freq'] /= df.pop('new').dt.days.fillna(1)
print (df)
         purch_freq
user_id            
1               2.0
2               1.0
3               0.0
```

Comment: This looks good, could you please give a brief explanation

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
x = df[df['prch_type'].eq('F')].groupby('user_id').agg({'prch_type': 'count', 'purchase_dt': lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).days if (x.max()-x.min()) else 1})
x['prch_freq'] = x['prch_type']/x['purchase_dt']
x.drop(['prch_type', 'purchase_dt'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**x:**

```
         prch_freq
user_id 
1        2.0
2        1.0
```

Comment: using this you can calculate your freq.

Comment: Your results don't match my last table, which is the exwpected result

Comment: @AlejandroA: Now check